# jQuery draggable constrain to parent's parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to constrain the movement of my draggable div within the parent of the parent.

```
<div class="grandparent'> // <-this is the div I would like to constrain to
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="draggable">
    ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know that I can contain within the parent like this:

```
$( ".draggable" ).draggable({
  containment: "parent"
});
```

And I know that I can contain within a specific div by passing in an `id`, but in my case I can't do that(`id`'s of the grandparent are being dynamically generated).

How can I contain within the parent's parent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.draggable').each(function(){
  var $el = $(this);
   $el.draggable({containment:$el.closest('.grandparent')    });
});
```

Use parents object find and for each iterator

Comment: Wouldn't `closest` be better than `parents`?

Comment: You are right, in this case closest is much better, because it should return first appeared parent not allparents. Updated answer.